# validates_associated not being triggered when I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables, `user` and `skill`, that are connected by a join table called `user_skill`. Each `UserSkill` has a `current_proficiency_level` and an `interest_level`.

Everything worked perfectly fine until I put a `validates_numericality_of :current_proficiency_level` on `UserSkill`. Now I get the following error when I try to save my `User` edit form. I only get the error when I have at least one non-numeric `current_proficiency_level`. When everything is valid, it saves fine.

> Failed to replace user_skills because one or more of the new records could not be saved.

This tells me that the `UserSkill` records probably aren't getting validated when I try to save my `User`. Here's my `User` class (with some irrelevant code omitted for clarity):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills
  validates_associated :user_skills

  def attach_skills(current_proficiency_levels, interest_levels)
    self.user_skills.destroy_all
    self.user_skills = Skill.all.map { |skill|
      user_skill = UserSkill.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_skill_id(self.id, skill.id)
      user_skill.assign_attributes(
        :current_proficiency_level => current_proficiency_levels[skill.id.to_s].negative_if_blank,
        :interest_level => interest_levels[skill.id.to_s].negative_if_blank
      )
      user_skill
    }
  end
end
```

And here is my `UserSkill` class. I haven't omitted anything here; it's just that short.

```
class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
  validates_numericality_of :current_proficiency_level
  validates_numericality_of :interest_level
end
```

Why isn't `validates_numericality_of` being run when I save my `User`?

Comment: can you tell when you get this error?

Comment: When I try to save my `User` edit form.

Comment: Maybe you have records in your database that are invalid (maybe they were created before you added the validation)?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I just did a `UserSkill.destroy_all` and tested again and no behavior changed. I did leave out the significant detail that I'm only getting this error when at least one `current_proficiency_level` value is invalid, though, so maybe that helps.

Comment: Did you ever got a solution for this? I'm having the same error.